# input button to update image name and location in joomla component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

[image]

`com_banner` in joomla has input type of text and two other buttons as shown above which helps in specifying and updating image name and value.

```
<div id="image">
    <?php foreach($this->form->getFieldset('image') as $field): ?>
       <?php echo $field->label; ?>
       <?php echo $field->input; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I also want to have such thing in my component but i've zero idea on how to achieve that. when the select button is clicked, i want to go to images folder and select file types pdf,doc or docx.

How is that button implemented in our custom components?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a `media` form field type.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/administrator/components/com_banners/models/forms/banner.xml#L197

You should specify `type="media"` in your form field.